# Should academics allow student to submit a possibly flawed paper?

Tags: phd, publications, reputation, supervision

I let a student associated with me (but who is not really my PhD student) submit a paper to a fairly-local meeting (some people do come from abroad). Because I'd been tasked with supporting the student, I let him put my name on the paper and also helped with the presentation, but I found the content unconvincing.  However, he was exploring an area that I knew little about and had little interest in, so I'd hoped he'd get reviews & (if accepted) discussion that would give him more guidance than I have been able to.

In fact, no one seemed as sceptical as I was of the work, and it got into the meeting and was presented both in our department and at the meeting with if anything positive comments.

However, yesterday I got an email from a postdoc who was cited in the paper (the student compared himself to the postdoc's work, the meeting's papers are on a website, Google Scholar alerted the postdoc) and was incensed at **the paper's low quality and inaccuracies**.  I think the postdoc is being a bit paranoid, but is broadly right on the technical issues. I have also previously noticed that one of my more-successful colleagues I've been collaborating with recently had a less tolerant attitude towards student publication than I do.

I'm wondering if I should put more effort on quality control.  The cost would be possibly stifling a student unnecessarily if I'm wrong, and allowing fewer students to have fewer presentation experiences since I'm already working flat out keeping up with giving feedback on their journal articles & dissertations.

Comment: Strongly advising a student against publishing a paper with major technical issues isn't "stifling" the student, it's helping the student avoid a mistake that can significantly harm their career.

Comment: Why do people reply in comments instead of answers?  Surely that defeats the purpose of stack exchange, which is to allow the community to weigh in on answers as well as questions?

Comment: I'm not attempting to answer your question (_Should academics allow students to submit..._). I only wanted to point out what I believe is a fallacy in the question (_the cost would be possibly stifling a student_).

Comment: @user14470: Short, one-sentence responses are not considered answers in the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: _I let him put my name on the paper...I found the content unconvincing_ — What? You were unconvinced by your own content? Or worse: You put your name on a paper without contributing any content?

Comment: I'm confused about one thing.  Did the paper get accepted?  If so, then maybe the conference's standards are also a concern.  If not, then how does this postdoc know about it?

Comment: @user14470 **Weak** (i.e. technically correct, but the content is cutting-edge or considered an important topic) or **wrong** (from inaccurate or sloppy to incorrect)?

Comment: Letting a student who is interested in submitting a paper do so if it is not up to your standards is dubious but debatable. Putting your name on a paper you did not contribute to is unethical. Putting your name on a paper you don't even agree with is crazy.

Comment: The paper used some of my ideas, and presented a working system, but the analysis and worth of the system are what's in question.  Ironically, the postdoc just admitted that the idea if not implementation was great and that + the weak quality has helped him find a new collaborator who wants to fix it.

Comment: @JeffE yes it was accepted. I was not certain of the value of the contribution, and trusted review to sort that, but basically the argument is that having a known author and/or institutional affiliation affects the prior on the quality of the work & skews the review process.  I've never bought that argument, but am using this question to reconsider it.

Comment: @aiesmail I was trying to get ff524 to put the effort into a real answer that could be debated. The fact you can't reference more than one person in a comment shows there isn't meant to be debate here.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal the system works, but I suspected (& the postdoc proved) the analysis is wrong and it wasn't really beyond the state of the art.

Comment: I'm confused by your phrasing "submit and possibly publish" which seems to suggest that you'd consider submitting something and then decide not to publish it. Why would you submit something without the intention of having it published? Doesn't that just waste the journal and referees' time? If you want to get comments on your work, mail it to colleagues and put it on the ArXiv.

Comment: @user14470 I edited the question. Do you like the changes?

Comment: If you believe the paper to be flawed, but don't understand it well enough to be sure, one solid option is to tell the student exactly that (and exactly why), and to refer them to a colleague who can answer the question more definitively.

Comment: What field are you in? I suspect this makes a difference here. Personally, coming from an artificial intelligence / artificial life background, I would say that when you publish at a "fairly local" meeting it's expected to be preliminary work, and that getting feedback is the primary purpose of presenting it, especially if it's student work. So I would regard this as a case of the system working correctly. But I suspect it rather depends on the norms of your field and the nature of the specific meeting.

Answer (score 47):

In my opinion, since you aren't the supervisor, it's not your role to stop the student from publishing.  If you are an expert in the subject of the publication and you don't think it's strong, you should advise them not to publish and explain why, but that's as far as you should go.

However, you "let him put [your] name on the paper" -- a paper which, by your own admission, you don't know much about!  Regardless of whether the co-author is a student, and regardless of the quality of the paper, the behavior you're describing is **wrong**.  In my field, it's actually **[forbidden by at least one of our professional societies](http://www.ams.org/about-us/governance/policy-statements/sec-ethics)**:

> All the authors listed for a paper . . . must have made a significant contribution to its content.

This is generally construed as meaning you should have done a significant part of the research **and** a significant part of the writing.

Now, violating this rule for a paper that you don't even have a high opinion of seems not only unethical but foolish.

I realize this is a harsh-sounding answer, but you have posted the question anonymously so I hope you don't mind me being frank.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, but most of the text of this answer does not address the question at all.

Comment: @ff524  You're right.  But if I ask whether I should do X or Y, and the right answer is to do Z, I hope that someone will tell me so.

Comment: I would upvote this, but I don't have sufficient reputation on this account yet.  I think I am making an error in agreeing to treat the student like one of my own, and should keep my name off his papers even if that does discourage him.  Thanks for being blunt, and I agree that Z is often the issue with an apparent X|Y question.

Comment: I haven't said the question is "answered" though yet as there may be more things I haven't thought of.

Comment: Whether he is "your own" student is utterly immaterial. Either you contributed to the paper, (therefore) deserve coauthorship, and (therefore) are responsible for its content, or you didn't, you don't, and you aren't.

Comment: Standards of authorship are completely different in mathematics vs. the life sciences. This level of involvement would not be totally unusual for a co-author in the life sciences who was the student's mentor, for instance. However, even there, adding your name to the author list makes you (at least partially) responsible for the paper's content. I wouldn't call it "unethical" to add your name in this situation but given your reservations, it seems unwise. A less formal conference or meeting, without published proceedings, might be a better venue for this type of "trial balloon."

Comment: @PatrickB., that in some fields unethical behavior is standard does not make it any more ethical.

Comment: @Kostya_I That's tautological. Unethical behavior is of course, by definition, unethical. I think most people would agree with the underlying principle that it is unethical to misrepresent your contributions to a paper. However, my point is that what authorship is *generally understood to represent* does demonstrably differ across fields. Therefore, whether you are in fact misrepresenting your contributions to the paper may depend on what exactly is expected of authors in that field (in the life sciences this will also depend on your position in the authorship list).

Comment: @PatrickB. the list of journals adhering to ICMJE guidelines, which explicitly prohibit the last authorship practice you are alluding to, seems to range across all life sciences I can think of. By contrast, I've never seen the practice of authorship based on subordination codified as accepted by any professional body. And yes, if it is *generally understood* that the king is naked and everybody is just lying, it's still a lie.

Comment: @Kostya_I What last-authorship practice exactly do you think I am "alluding to"? It is entirely possible from what the author wrote that they did in fact fulfill those four ICMJE criteria, especially given their clarification below (there is of course not enough information to make an unambiguous determination): they contributed to the study design, revised the paper critically, approved the submission, and recognize that they are accountable for the publication. My point, again, is that those criteria are not uniform across fields.

Answer (score 22):

I think we can distinguish two situations here:

1. The work is not convincing because it is still **preliminary**. In this situation, even if the results might prove wrong latter, I would see no objection to send the student to present a talk or a poster about it, as long as the preliminary nature of the work is clearly stated. I might give him the opportunity to meet other researchers, find new ideas or even build collaboration based on these first results.
2. The work is not convincing because the **results are flawed**, the protocol is not robust or the techniques might not be adequate. In such situation, as @ff524 said, I would advise not to let the student present the work in public meetings. It will be unproductive both for the student and the advisor (as you experienced).

Comment: This assumes you can reliably discriminate the two cases.  Preliminary results may be flawed, and you may not have detected that flaw.  Is it worth stifling the student until you can invest the time to be certain there are no flaws, or do you engage the academic community in that checking?

Comment: @user14470 If you can't invest the time to tell whether there are flaws, you absolutely should not be an author of the paper.

Comment: Well, I disagree with that – again, an arbitrarily brilliant paper can have arbitrarily subtle flaws, you invest some time in any paper, but how much for which target audiences.

Comment: @user14470 I think as long as you state clearly that the results are preliminary, it is not a problem to share them, even if further experiment prove them wrong. The preliminary sharing might bring some interesting discussions.

Comment: @William If you'd put that as an answer instead of a comment I wouldn't have had to add my own (see below).

Comment: @user14470 sorry for that... I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

As a mathematician, I had the same first reaction to this question as several other answerers and commenters: It's wrong to be a co-author of a paper that is just someone else's work.  But I need to temper that reaction with the fact that other fields have rather different standards. In particular, in some (maybe even all?) of the experimental sciences, it is standard practice for the head of the lab to be a co-author of everything that comes out of that lab, whether or not the head actually did any of the research or even understood the research. As far as I can tell, the rationale for this is that the head of the lab gets the grants that make everybody else's work possible. The question here suggests that this sort of thing might be involved here ("I'd been tasked with supporting the student"), so co-authorship might not be quite as crazy or as unethical as it looks to a mathematician. Even in the experimental sciences, though, the head of the lab is (as far as I know) expected to make sure the work is good (and is held responsible if it is not).

Comment: Good answer.  It isn't only money though, the money comes from ideas.  Lab members benefit from an intellectual atmosphere, direction, a set of literature other lab members have identified as being worth extending, etc.  But anyway (as I've clarified in the comments & in an answer I've floated) I did contribute to the paper.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to break the "don't answer your own question" norm here, but I want to float an answer.  First, I *did* contribute to the paper (suggested direction of research) and the system presented *does* work.  My issue was whether this new system was a real academic contribution, which I left up to the academic process to determine.

Overnight, the postdoc who initially complained a) admitted that the idea was great if not entirely well executed and b) told me he's found a new prestigious collaboration writing a better paper.  In my mind, this is how academia is supposed to work.  So my proposed answer is "yes".  I leave it to you folks to vote up or down.

Comment: _suggested direction of research_ — This is not universally regarded as sufficient contribution for coauthorship.

Comment: You answer is _Academics should allow students to submit a possibly flawed paper because I did it once and it turned out not to be so flawed_?

Comment: My answer is "students should be allowed to use the review and presentation process the way it's intended to be used, to contribute plausible ideas to the community and let the community correct, improve, or reject them". As to whether even weak students deserve the branding of an academic institution including its faculty, well, students probably suffer as much as institutions from bad admissions decisions, and once in probably deserve a level playing ground to try to prove themselves.  But I for one am not letting myself get dragged into this situation again.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is, to what end? What purpose are you serving by allowing such work to be published? The community does not benefit, as the work is subpar and (apparently) flawed. The student does not benefit, as (a) the experience is different from actual publishing with more rigorous review processes and (b) their reputation is tarnished. You receive no benefit for the same reasons.

The only possible benefit I see is that the student gains experience in informal writing and presenting, which they can already gain through group lab meetings without the possible repercussions relating to their reputation. In short, this appears on all fronts to be a pretty bad practice.

Comment: The benefit is getting the opinion of more people than are in the lab, especially since it is a new area for us.  I now consider (see my floated "answer" / update) that I did get a benefit, since the postdoc is now in a new collaboration, writing a better system AND provided a critique of the student's work that the student couldn't have gotten in the lab & didn't get from the reviewers.

Comment: @user14470 I guess that this comes down to how much risk you're willing to take for the possible good outcome. I would venture that the risk here far outweights any possible benefits. Do remember that you still can't observe possible negative reputation effects, and you may never know the full negative effect of this paper.